# Over voltage, over current and surge testing

Tags: power-supply, testing

I used a [TI reference design](http://www.ti.com/tool/PMP11612?keyMatch=null&tisearch=tidesigns-power#technicaldocuments)to prototype a 120VAC to 5VDC 2A power supply on a PCB and it's been working fine for a couple of months. I want to run some basic tests to see if the PCB is safe under over voltage and over current scenarios. Is there a cheap way to go about doing that? I came across Hipot testers, but they were pretty expensive.

Comment: Are you trying to test its integrity? If so, why? TI already has information on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only thing not given is HIPOT which depends on creepage clearance and T1

http://www.ti.com/lit/pdf/tidubr1

HIPOT 4kVdc testers are simple to make with line multiplier and 1000k 1W current limiter with variac or Triac dimmer
 for a few second ramp to charge up line filter caps. 1mA analog current meter is needed with protection diodes